# How to send schedule emails using php without cron job

Tags: php, email, automation

I want send schedule mails using my php website, I don't want to use cron job because shared hosting environments might not provide all the functions.

So how can I send schedule mails with my site. Please let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Laxmilal Menaria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out:

http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/

> The purpose of this website is to
>   allow website administrators without
>   cronjob service on their own host, run
>   cronjobs.

It claims to be free service although I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 2):

You can send emails using visitor hits. Write somewhere (db) the last time you runned job.

```
$now = time();
if ($now > $last_sent_time + 3600) {
  // code that sends emails
  // goes here ....... 

  set_last_sent_time($now);
}
```

I think you got the idea. You should put this code on every request to site. The example sends emails every hour.

Comment: "The example sends emails every hour." So long as you have visitors often enough. If you only get 2 visitors a day, obviously you'd only get emails being sent twice a day. You'll also need to store the last_sent_time in a database or file to read later. This is really your only option though.

Comment: Totally correct. But you can configure cron on your home (or whatever) computer, which will send http request to your site every hour (launch a browser and navigate to your site).