# daily / monthly counter for an html / javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make 2 different quizzes, a monthly quiz and a daily quiz, so the daily quiz is shown every day to the logged in user and the monthly quiz every 30 days.

Any ideas how to implement this with html / javascript? I think I need a counter variable to proof counter < 7. How can I count the days between last quiz and now?

Comment: Are you open to using a DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I asked somewhat a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234659/how-to-make-a-user-wait-with-laravel/42235428#42235428) a while ago and this is one of the responses I got. My question was more to with how to make use a wait X amount of days before they could leave a review on my ecommerce store. Hopefully this will guide you in the right direction.

As I understand your use case, you need a persistent storage method to remember how many days have passed since a particular action/thing. There are, in general, 4 methods of persistent storage:

**1. Cookies:**

- Storage: Client Side
- Specific: Unique to user machine and domain
- Persistence Time: Can last forever unless the user specifically
  deletes the cookie
- Common Use Cases: Saved preferences

**2. Session**

- Storage: Server Side (depends on driver)
- Specific: Specific to user (but depends on driver)
- Persistence Time: Usually expires in a couple of hours, but can be extended
- Common Use Cases: Persistence layer from one request to another (like shopping cart, popup notifications after action triggers)

**3. Caching**

- Storage: Server Side
- Specific: Generally application specific (but can be user specific)
- Persistence Time: Generally an hour to a couple of days
- Common Use Cases: Application specific storage use cases (e.g. total number of hits, most popular pages, database query caching, view caching)

**4. Database**

- Storage: Server Side
- Specific: Can be user or app specific
- Persistence Time: Forever until deleted
- Common Use Cases: Longer term data persistence layer (e.g. user details)

Comment: wow, that's a great answer, so database seems to be the best solution. thanks a lot!

Comment: NP. I have updated my answer with a link to the original question I got this from, feel free to browse.